# Grouping multi-dimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I can't focus right now and my mind keeps playing tricks on me with the solution to this.

I've tried a multitude of options but they keep not working.. Sigh.

Say I have a string as such; `a.b.c|a.b.d|a.b.e|f|f.g|f.h|i`, I want to create a new array (or object) as the following

```
A > B > C, D, E    
F > G, H    
I
```

With `>` being a nested array, `,` being an element in the parent array.

These should be able to continue nesting a multitude of times, e.g. `A > B > C > D > E > F, D`

Any guidance? I've tried exploding the string and then those strings to an array - this array holds `A > B > C, A > B > D, A > B > E` etc., I just can't get my head around to how to combine them efficiently.

I started with just looping over each element in the array and checking if the parents' key exists, but that was failing. Any help is appreciated as I'm incredibly tired, quite shocking I can do such a simple task.

Comment: can you provide an input string and the expected array please?

Comment: Please show us your source code, maybe somebody finds the mistake made.

Comment: I can't work out how your input string matches up to your expected output.

Comment: If I understand, you want `$a = array('b' => array('c', 'd', 'e'));` Such that c, d, e are elements within Array b, and Array b is an element of Array a. The next one, Array H is an element of Array G, which is an element of Array F?

Comment: in your code example, wouldn't it be `F > G, H` ??

Comment: PHP arrays are not multi-dimensional. What you describe as your objective is not a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Yes, it should be F > G, H. And ah, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// read line from standard input
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));

echo "Line: $line\n"; // debug

// split lines by |
$segments = explode('|', $line);

print_r($segments); // debug

// prepare output array
$md_array = array();

// walk through the segments
foreach($segments as $segment) {
    // set pointer to output array
    $current = &$md_array;
    // split segment by .
    $tokens = explode('.', $segment);

    print_r($tokens); // debug

    foreach($tokens as $token) {
        echo "working on $token\n";

        // if key is not included in the array, create empty array
        if( ! array_key_exists($token, $current) ) {
            $current[$token] = array();
        }
        // pass the pointer to following sub-section
        $current = &$current[$token];
    }
}

// print out the output
print_r($md_array);

?>
```

Testing the script

```
echo "a.b.c|a.b.d|a.b.e|f|f.g|f.h|i" | php test.php
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [d] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [e] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [f] => Array
        (
            [g] => Array
                (
                )

            [h] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [i] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Not quite what I want. It shouldn't create arrays, as in g and h should be arrays but the string 'g' and the string 'h'.

Comment: if you parse the structure using foreach($node as $key => $value) and test if the $value is empty array, then you can consider the $key as the item of current node. If I'll put each item as a string instead of key to another array, it would put also f as an item, because there's a single f in the list. If that's what you want, then you can modify if( ! array_key_exists($token, $current) ) {
            $current[$token] = array();
        } to if( ! array_key_exists($token, $current) ) {
            $current[$token] = array(); $current[] = $token;
        }

Comment: No, f should be an array that holds two string values - g, h. `[f] => ['g', 'h']`. I'll probably figure a way to edit it in the morning, as I can't right now. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Want to thank Richard for his solution, which allowed me  to achieve my aim.

See the code below:

```
public static function permissions($permList) {
    $segments = explode('|', $permList);
    $md_array = array();
    foreach($segments as $segment) {
        $current = &$md_array;
        $tokens = explode('.', $segment);
        $x = 0;
        foreach($tokens as $token) {                
            if(!array_key_exists($token, $current) ) {
                if(count($tokens) > $x+1)
                    $current[$token] = array();
                else
                    $current[] = $token;
            }
            if(count($tokens) > $x+1)
                $current = &$current[$token];
            $x++;
        }
    }
    return $md_array;
}
```

If I input `a.b.c|a.b.d|a.b.e|f|f.g|f.h|i`, I am returned with the expected output above.

Many thanks.